# React property is undefined for creating custom HTML tag

Tags: reactjs

Currently I am creating a title component that can be dynamically created by adding a level property e.g. level=1 creating a `<h1>` tag. So my code is looking like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const CustomLevel = `h${this.props.level}`;

const Title = ({ level, size, text }) => (
  <CustomLevel level={level} size={size}>
    {text}
  </CustomLevel>
);

Title.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  level: PropTypes.oneOf(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']),

  /** This will set the size of the text */
  size: PropTypes.oneOf(['xSmall', 'small', 'medium', 'big'])
};

Title.defaultProps = {
  size: 'medium',
  level: '2'
};

/**
 * @component
*/
export default Title;
```

But I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'level' of undefined` in `const CustomLevel`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing

```
const CustomLevel = `h${this.props.level}`;

const Title = ({ level, size, text }) => (
  <CustomLevel level={level} size={size}>
    {text}
  </CustomLevel>
);
```

where `props` is undefined you can define your `CustomLevel` inside of your `Title` component:

```
const Title = ({ level, size, text }) => {
  const CustomLevel = `h${level}`;

  return (
    <CustomLevel level={level} size={size}>
      {text}
    </CustomLevel>
  );
};
```

Comment: @RonaldZwiers Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `level` of `this.props` outside the `function component` which is not available or `undefined`. You should note that `props` is only available as a parameter to the `function component`.

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6wyy5oxjqw) of your problem.